# Value Assignment with Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Can you please tell me why the results I am getting from the following code is not correct.

I have 2 fieldnames, one called CheckAmount and the other called ckeckNumber.

CheckNumber of varchar(25) and checkAmount is of Money data type.

Whenever a check amount is inserted into the DB, the associated check Number is also inserted.

When cash is inserted, however, checkNumber column is blank.

I am trying insert 'Cash Payment' into the blank column in CHeck Number column when chas is inserted into cashAmount colum with the following code:

```
select 
 CASE 
  WHEN checknumber ='' AND isnull(checkAmount ,'0.0') is not null 
  THEN 'Cash Payment' 
 ELSE checknumber 
END As checknumber 
from mytable
```

Problem is even if check Number column is not empty (not necessarily null), and the cash Amount is not empty (again we are not talking about Null), then the code still inserts 'Cash Payment'

Any ideas? I can explain further if needed; I don't want to be too wordy.

```
25411025    25411025    16  1.00    1.0000
25411026    25411026    16  2.00    2.0000
    x   0   0.00    0.0000
    x   0   0.00    0.0000
    x   0   0.00    0.0000

ClientID   CheckNumber CheckAmount CashAmount
========== =========== =========== ==========
0000000340    25411025        1.00       0.00
0000000340    25411026        2.00       0.00
0000000340                    0.00       3.00
0000000340                    0.00      15.00
0000000340                    0.00       0.00
```

Comment: Why do you say that you are trying to do an insert and you are doing a select instead?

Answer (score 1):

the `isnull(checkAmount, '0.0')` will convert a null checkAmount amount to '0.0', so I don't see how the result could ever be null. That part of your case statement will always evaluate to true.

Are you sure you don't want that part to read:

```
...AND isnull(checkAmount, '0.0') = '0.0'
```

Or am I not understanding your problem?

**UPDATE:**

based on your comments I think you are wanting to verify that cheknumber is blank and the **cashAmount** column is not zero:

```
select 
 CASE 
  WHEN isnull(checknumber, '')  = '' AND isnull(cashAmount, 0) <> 0
  THEN 'Cash Payment' 
 ELSE checknumber 
END As checknumber 
from mytable
```

Hope this is correct.

Comment: PaulStock, thanks so much. What I am trying to say is that if cashAmount column has some money, and checkNumber column doesn't have any number, then put 'Cash Payment' text into that blank check Number column. I think the real issue is handling whether checkAmount is NULL or empty. I believe those are 2 different things. Same goes for checkNumber. I hope this is clearer. Again, thanks

Comment: If this helps, as far as the checkNumber column is concerned, some of the values are NULL and some are empty boxes. So, the ones that show null are the ones that display the 'Cash Payment' text. The ones that show empty space don't. ALl the boxes for checkAmount column either have money or 0.00. None is NULL or empty.

Comment: I'm confused. In your code you were referencing `checkAmount` column but in your comments you are talking about `cashAmount` column. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part. It should be checkAMount. sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Please see my updated answer and see if this helps.  If the column should be `checkAmount` instead of `cashAmount` then I think the `<>` should be changed to `=`

Comment: That's it! It is working good now. THank you  Paul for your patience. You understood better what I have been bumbling. Aaron, my gratitude to you as well. Thanks to both of you, especially you Paul and please pardon me for the confusion.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. If answer is correct, would you mind marking it as such by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What does this yield for the rows that are "wrong"?

```
SELECT
  checknumber,
  cn_fallback = COALESCE(NULLIF(RTRIM(checknumber), ''), 'x'),
  cn_length = DATALENGTH(checknumber),
  checkAmount,
  ca_fallback = COALESCE(checkAmount, 0.0)
FROM mytable;
```

Does this query yield the result you're after? I'm still trying to figure out if you want an empty string in the second checknumber column when there is "no check and no cash":

```
SELECT *, CASE 
  WHEN RTRIM(checknumber) = '' 
  AND CheckAmount = 0
  AND CashAmount > 0
  THEN 'Cash Payment' 
 ELSE checknumber 
END As checknumber 
FROM dbo.mytable;
```

Comment: Aaron, thanks a lot. I show the last 5 rows of data above. The signicance of those 5 rows is that they illustrate the issue that I am having. Looking at the above, the x on the last row should not have been there because as you can see, the first 2 rows are check numbers. The next 2 rows have cash amount even though it is not in the query and the check number is blank. so far so good, It is the last row with x that should not have x because no check and no cash.

Comment: I don't think you're describing the problem very well. Can you show the actual data that is in the table, rather than a result of a query?

Comment: Ok, I just pasted the actual data from the db. The first column is clientID, the second column is checkNumber, the third column is CheckAmount and the last column is Cash Amount. Again, notice that the first 2 rows have check number and check amount and no money in cash column. The next 2 rows have no check number and no checkamount. That's because the money is in the cash column. These 2 rows should have the 'Cash Payment' text. The last row has no check number, no check amount and no cash amount. That last row should have no 'Cash Payment' text. Hope it is clearer and thanks again.

Comment: Those blank values in the Cash Amount still don't tell anyone what is *IN* that column. Is it NULL, a space, a tab, a cr/lf pair, etc.? Are we supposed to guess? Is the column money, varchar, or something else? Why isn't there just an amount column and a separate column to indicate the type? Even you can't keep the "check amount" and "cash amount" columns straight...

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't keep them straight because I am not sure what formatting to use. The CheckAmount and CashAmount are of Money data types. CheckNumber is varchar. Good question about having one Amount column separate colum to indicate type. Unfortunately, I am given someone else's work to manage. I don't think NULL is in those blank colums as I am sure it will have said null. There are a bunch of null values but the ones I posted aren't nulls and those are the ones that are not displaying the 'Cash Paymnent' text. When I entered data for testing, I didn't entere anything into them.

Comment: If those columns are MONEY then how are any of them "blank"?

Comment: They are not blank. I don't believe that's what I said. Only check number values are blank, a lot of them but not all of them. THe checkamount and cash amount columns are either 0.00 or they have actual amount. I think you felt that way because the columns shifted left.

Comment: If you look at the sample data you posted, what would *you* think?

Comment: I've edited it to look better. But we still have no idea what "blank" really means and frankly I'm quite dizzy from trying to reverse engineer the word problems about check amount, cash amount, "no check and no cash", ...

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 WHEN checknumber ='' AND isnull(checkAmount ,'0.0') is not null 
  THEN 'Cash Payment' 
 ELSE checknumber
```

To SELECT the way that you are indicating it should look something like this:

```
SELECT
    ClientID
    ,CheckNumber
    ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(CheckNumber,'') <> '' THEN CheckAmount ELSE 0 END AS CheckAmount
    ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(CheckNumber,'') = '' THEN CashAmount ELSE 0 END AS CashAmount
FROM dbo.myTable
```

It's as simple as that...either there's a check number or there isn't; either it's cash or it's not.